# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting, Python

Tags: python

I dont know why the error is coming up. Its a program to show the numbers that include a 7 and are a multiple of 7.

```
import sys
Numbers = raw_input()
Answer = 0
NumbersList = Numbers.split()
Length = len(NumbersList)
for num in range(0, Length):
    N = NumbersList [num-1]
    ListNumber = list(str(N))
    if (N == 0):
        print(Answer)
    elif (num == Length):
    print(Answer)
    elif (N % 7 == 0):
        Answer = Answer + 1
    elif 7 in ListNumber:
        Answer = Answer + 1


sys.stdout.flush()
```

New Question. My elif statement at the bottom doesnt seem to work.
The input is a list of numbers from 0-100. Stop at a 0. Answer = Numbers with %7 = 0 or with a 7 in it

```
import sys
Numbers = raw_input()
Answer = 0
NumbersList = Numbers.split()
Length = len(NumbersList)
for num in range(0, Length):
    N = NumbersList [num]
    ListNumber = list(str(N))
    if (int(N) == 0):
        print(Answer)
        break
    elif (num == Length):
        if (int(N) % 7 == 0):
            Answer = Answer + 1
        elif 7 in ListNumber:
            Answer = Answer + 1
        print(Answer)
    elif (int(N) % 7 == 0):
        Answer = Answer + 1
    elif 7 in ListNumber:
        Answer = Answer + 1


sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: `N % 7` when `N` is an integer would work. However, `N` is a string, so it tries to substitute the following `7` into the string. There are no placeholders so you get the exception.

Comment: so '567' is valid output, since it has a '7'?  or you are only looking for multiples of 7 including 7

Comment: don't use reserve keywords like `list` unless you are trying to actually convert that to a list.

Comment: Ty, now this error has stopped. I just cant seem to get the part good with the if 7 in ListNumber. The last elif part doesnt seem to work. The input is a list of numbers from 0-100. Stop at a 0. Answer = Numbers with %7 = 0 or with a 7 in it

Comment: If you have a new question then you need to ask a whole new question. If this question was answered then you need to either accept an an answer or write your own answer. People will be more inclined to help you if you have a history of accepting and voting up answers.

Answer (score 0):

Stealing @PeterWood's comment, you need to convert the input to an integer first.

```
 N = int( NumbersList [num-1] )
```

You may also want to consider using `for num in NumberList` and reading https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for a guide to good practice.

This works for me (or doesn't error):

```
import sys
Numbers = raw_input()
Answer = 0
NumbersList = Numbers.split()
Length = len(NumbersList)
for num in range(0, Length):
    N = int( NumbersList [num-1])
    ListNumber = list(str(N))
    if (N == 0):
        print(Answer)
    elif (num == Length):
        print(Answer)
    elif (N % 7 == 0):
        Answer = Answer + 1
    elif 7 in ListNumber:
        Answer = Answer + 1

print Answer
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: It still won't work, either you call list() with a `str` or `int`

Comment: `  ListNumber = list(str(N))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: dufuq!? Just remove that line anyway. You don't use it anyway

Comment: i do, at elif 7 in ListNumber

Comment: Doh :$ Sorry. Anyway, the code I pasted works for me on Python 2.7